# Mapping API result to class, should I use reflection and is this a case of DataAdapter design pattern?

Tags: c#, api, design-patterns, reflection

It is my first time using an API and I am not entirely sure about the good practices regarding it. I am using a third party API that returns me a class 'A' in C#, that is not quite compatible with my DTO class 'MyA'. I obviously have to map it to my entity, but I don't know what the best way to do it is. I have read of the Data Adapter pattern and from what I understand, it has the purpose to act as a bridge between two incompatible interfaces. Those classes share some properties, but differ in more important ones, so I wonder if this pattern is what I am looking for.

I believe I could create a base class that uses reflection to map the matching properties for the generic case, and build on top of that for the different properties. I have however heard that reflections should be avoided, so another approach would be to manually map even the shared properties. This would probably be easier to do now, but it is not maintainable at all, involves some avoidable logic repetition, and overall contradicts good design practices.

Would my situation be considered a case usage of DataAdapter? From the definitions I read, I think yes, however the posts I found were predominantly about using different data sources (XML,JSON,CSV), not just classes in the same language with some properties that differ?

Comment: It's unreadable, not just chaotic. Use proper sentences and paragraphs so people can read it. Post the code instead of describing it. If you want to map one object to another, there are some libraries like AutoMapper that can help, by mapping properties and types based on names and some conventions. If the types are too different though, specifying how to map one to another will take as much if not more code than writing a `new TargetDTO { SomeProperty=source.SomeVeryDifferentProperty[0].Name,...}`

Comment: I haven't written code yet, I don't know which approach to follow and I don't know where to start from. We can't use AutoMappers, and I considered implementing the code snippet you wrote, but I have more classes I need to fetch from the API, multiple times in multiple places, so I wonder if this is good?

Comment: You may not have to write any code. What classes are you trying to map?

Comment: class A to class 'MyA', class B to class 'MyB' and three more of a similar structure. My problems are mostly the differing properties in class A and 'MyA', which is an overall occuring problem in the application, since MyA and MyB have a one to many relationship and MyA and MyC many to many.

Comment: That doesn't explain anything - that's any class to any other. What differing properties? How different? Post the code in the question itself. Some things can be mapped automatically, others need configuration. If everything needs configuration though, you gain nothing over constructing objects by hand.

Comment: The way to do this is to 1. Instantiate an instance of `MyA`, and 2. set its properties based on what you see in `A`. This is called "mapping." The simplest thing is to write code that does the mapping. If you have a crap ton of properties you might consider autogenerated code or a tool like automapper. But those are not necessary. Just set the properties. There doesn't have to be anything clever about it.

Comment: Q: Should I use .NET reflection to map an API result to a class?  A: NOOOOO!  Q: Should I use the [Adapter Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/adapter/csharp/example)?  A: Not a bad idea, but you still have to decide how to "implement" it.  Try some simple, concrete approaches first.  1) See if you can just use C# classes (or Entity Framework classes),  2) Perhaps you might also consider a 3rd party library like AutoMapper, as Panagiotis Kanavos suggested below.

Answer (score 2):

The question is very hard to read but I suspect it asks how to map between two similar DTO types. There are libraries that do this, for example [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/).

AutoMapper can map between types based on property names and some conventions that allow it to handle eg flattening, or mapping method results to properties, eg `GetTotal()` to `Total {get;set;}`. It's possible to configure specific mappings for properties with different names, but if the types are too different, it may not be worth it.

AutoMapper uses Reflection to find which properties to map but caches that information instead of recalculating it every time.

For example, given a User and UserDTO :

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
}

public class UserDTO
{
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

AutoMapper can map between them directly :

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();
})
;
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
...
UserDto dto = mapper.Map<UserDto>(user);
```

The [Flattening example](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html) shows how properties of a complex model can be mapped to a simpler DTO based on naming conventions, eg `Customer.Name` gets mapped to `CustomerName`. It also shows how `Order.GetTotal()` gets mapped to

This complex source model:

```
public class Order
{
    private readonly IList<OrderLineItem> _orderLineItems = new List<OrderLineItem>();

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public OrderLineItem[] GetOrderLineItems()
    {
        return _orderLineItems.ToArray();
    }

    public void AddOrderLineItem(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        _orderLineItems.Add(new OrderLineItem(product, quantity));
    }

    public decimal GetTotal()
    {
        return _orderLineItems.Sum(li => li.GetTotal());
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLineItem
{
    public OrderLineItem(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        Product = product;
        Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Product Product { get; private set; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set;}

    public decimal GetTotal()
    {
        return Quantity*Product.Price;
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

can be mapped to this simple DTO simply using conventions :

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

without special configuration :

```
// Configure AutoMapper

var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>{ 
    cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>();
});
```

```
// Complex model

var customer = new Customer
    {
        Name = "George Costanza"
    };
var order = new Order
    {
        Customer = customer
    };
var bosco = new Product
    {
        Name = "Bosco",
        Price = 4.99m
    };
order.AddOrderLineItem(bosco, 15);

// Perform mapping

OrderDto dto = mapper.Map<Order, OrderDto>(order);
```

It's possible to specify complex mappings when it's not possible to map by convention :

```
public class CalendarEvent
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class CalendarEventForm
{
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public int EventHour { get; set; }
    public int EventMinute { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

In this case each `Event` property can be mapped individually, with a full mapping expression:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
  cfg.CreateMap<CalendarEvent, CalendarEventForm>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EventDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date.Date))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EventHour, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date.Hour))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EventMinute, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date.Minute)));
```

This makes sense when only a few properties need custom mapping, eg when only 2 out of 10 properties need mapping. It also helps when mappings can occur in many places.

For this example though, 3 out of 4 properties need mapping and the "manual" code is actually simpler than the configuration itself:

```
var dest=new CalendarEventForm {
    Title     =scr.Title,
    EventDate =src.Date.Date,
    EventHour =src.Date.Hour,
    EventMinute =src.Date.Minute,
};
```